# Draw image within a shape using Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am currently working on image manipulation in canvas and Javascript. I am using fabric.js for it. I just want the user to upload an image and merge it with the template provided by us. ie.,

[image: the Template]

I want to show the uploaded image only in the empty circle in the center and they can adjust by dragging it.

- If I keep the template as upper layer the user can't drag and adjust since the canvas is filled with template.
- If I keep uploaded image as the upper layer then the image will overflow the circle.

How can I solve this by giving my user an easy to use interface? I tried for **ClipTo** function in fabric.js but it doesn't work with image Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [overlayImage](http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setOverlayImage) is what you're after.

Take a look at [customization demo](http://fabricjs.com/customization/) for example:

[image: Example of overlayImage]

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c13');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({ 
  radius: 30, 
  fill: '#f55', 
  top: 100, 
  left: 100 
});
canvas.add(circle);
canvas.setOverlayImage('../assets/jail_cell_bars.png', 
  canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I place a Text object over an overlay image?

Comment: Not really. `overlayImage` is meant to be drawn on top of everything else. It's a simple `drawImage` call that happens at the very end of the rendering loop. But if this image is transparent in the middle, do you really need it to be on top? It would look as if any content within that circular area is clipped by it.

Comment: but my app really requires 3 layers. 1) user uploaded image which is shown only through the transparent area of template (ref image in question) 2) Template something like the image in question 3) the text on top of the template. Can I draw something to the upper-canvas in fabricjs without disturbing overlayimage?

Comment: Yeah, that could be a little complicated. I haven't thought of such use cases when designing fabric. You can use "after:render" callback, and manually draw something on `canvas.contextContainer` (using native `strokeText` method, for example). But it's not easy to render fabric objects on top. Maybe through somewhat of a hack of creating text object, then calling its `_render` method in context of `contextContainer` — `textObj._render(canvas.contextContainer)` (in "after:render" callback) or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could draw both the photo and the template into the canvas. I'm not sure about fabric.js, but if you called the canvas functions directly you would simply...

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.DrawImage(user_img, x,y);
ctx.DragImage(template_imb, 0, 0);
```

When the user drags the mouse update x and y and redraw both layers. Obviously make sure the hole in the template is transparent. You can add width and height to the DrawImage call if you want the user to be able to resize the image, just provide some kind of control the change them.

Answer (score 0):

The more difficult method is to create a temporary (off-screen) canvas.  Using `globalCompositeOperation=source-in`, draw the image over a mask image, then `getImageData` from there and `putImageData` onto your destination canvas.

But if [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371773) works for you, it is much more straightforward.